Date String with Time Zone Offset
I have to process an input file that contains "dates with offsets" (like 2024-04-29+02:00). Basically, I know how to parse that … but I have no real idea which target type I have to choose – target is Java here.
Only java.time.LocalDate has no time portion, but it also has no time zone or offset. On the other hand, all types that have an offset or a time zone will have a time portion, too.
Of course I can interpret a "date with offset" as "date at midnight with offset" and parse it to java.time.OffsetDateTime, so that 2024-04-29+02:00 would be just the abbreviation for 2024-04-29T00:00:00.0+02:00. Perhaps it is even meant this way …
I tried to find any references that would explain how to interpret a date with an offset, but I have not found anything – in particular no authoritative source. Unfortunately, the original ISO 8601 is behind a paywall … but as none of the various sources discussing the  ISO standard ever mentioned a format "date with offset", I doubt that it would help here.
The description of the input file is not helpful; the respective field is just described there as "date".
Does anybody have an idea how to handle "dates with offset"?

This is not an official ISO format. Only the sender can tell what is meant with this string. The possible interpretations range from an instant (e.g. 0 AM in the given time zone) over just a local date (ignoring the time zone) to a 24 hour interval.

I think I would do the safest thing and define a record OffsetDate(LocalDate date, ZoneId zone) type.  No need to guess, that way.

@VGR – Might be safe, but would require to implement to whole logic that exists already for any of the java.time type for my new OffsetDate type. Not to mention that I have to teach the already existing application logic how to use it …

@Henry – At least it is not an interval: one field containing such a date is named <IntrBkSttlmDt> or "Interbank Settlement Date". And that is clearly a "point in time" and not an interval. Ok, the same format could have different meanings in different contexts, but then I would expect more details in the description … but yes, asking the sender should help. Unfortunately, I do not have direct access to them. But if this seems to be the only way to go, I have to … thx!!

@tquadrat The point made in your last Comment should be made in the body of your Question.

There is a predefined formatter for that format, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE. Meaning you can pick out the date and offset parts individually with LocalDate.parse(string, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE) and DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE.parse(string, ZoneOffset::from).

Similar but older: How to convert String to Date with TimeZone?. There still are a couple of interesting answers IMO. There’s also an interesting answer by JodaStephen here.

Most likely interpretation, is storing in "dates with offset" format to let any person, who is in another timezone, to know how many hours are left before a day in a specific timezone starts.
One possible useful scenario is tracking how many hours before a holiday starts in a specific country.

Also, another thing to consider is, what you, as the developer, are looking to do out of this date.And if it will affect you if the interpretation suddenly changes.


As for representing the string into an object, I personally do not see anything wrong with using java.time.OffsetDateTime.But if you like to nitpick at the class/datatype naming not matching the actual intention, you could probably just create an class that extends OffsetDateTime, but literally does the same thing, except renamed to OffsetDate.(Or you can import it as well, if you are already using ThreeTen's library.)

A date with an offset does not tell you "how many hours are left before a day in a specific timezone starts". That claim makes no sense to me.

@BasilBourque More specifically, you can use your now() to check against that date with a Offset, to figure out how many hours before the specific day in that specific timezone starts; Why would you need it? Depends on the domain, but given there exists an OffsetDate object provided by a library, shows that there is going to be some extremely niche domains out there that will require it. Regardless, I was just coming up with one possible use-case, but the actual use case will have to depend on how OP wants to use it....

You speak of a time zone. But we have no time zone in the given scenario. We have only an offset. You cannot determine when a specific day will start based only on an offset. See my Answer for more discussion on this point.

TIL; Though possible use-case still stands: for coordination of activities across different regions.

Please post a concrete code example in your Answer. I don’t understand.

Date-with-offset makes no sense

"dates with offsets" (like 2024-04-29+02:00).

There is no meaning to a date with offset.
The day of a particular date starts at different moments (and ever different time-of-day!) in different time zones.
And days differ in length by date in different time zones. A day may run 23 hours, 25 hours, 23.5 hours, and so on. The offset offers no clue there.

Only java.time.LocalDate has no time portion, but it also has no time zone or offset. On the other hand, all types that have an offset or a time zone will have a time portion, too.

You missed the class OffsetTime, the class that represents a time-of-day with an offset-from-UTC but no date. And this class makes no sense, because a time-with-offset makes no sense. Presumably OffsetTime was included in the java.time framework only for compatibility with SQL. The SQL standards committee is known for making some screwy decisions. And declaring  the TIME WITH TIME ZONE type was one of their worst. This type simply makes no sense if you think about. You cannot do anything with a time+offset. The SQL standard barely touches on date-time matters, and what little they declared is not well thought-out, not particularly informed, and not documented/explained. For another matter, the SQL standard uses the term "TIME ZONE" where they really mean "OFFSET".
Your more general point is correct… Indicating an offset only makes sense when you have both a date and a time-of-day. When you include an offset, you have determined a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

I have to process an input file that

You should communicate to the publisher of your data that there is no meaning to a date-with-offset. Inquire as to their intentions. And educate them about the ISO 8601 standard.
The publisher might have meant to represent the first moment of the day. But that should have been done with a time-of-day. Never assume the day starts at 00:00:00. Some dates in some time zones start at another time such as 01:00. So we cannot determine the start of the day with only a date and offset — we need a time zone rather than offset.
Let java.time determine the start of day.
Here is an example for Jordan.
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2021-03-26" ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Amman" ) ;
ZonedDateTime startOfDayAmman = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;

See this code run at Ideone.com.

startOfDayAmman.toString() = 2021-03-26T01:00+03:00[Asia/Amman]

Notice how that day began at 1 AM. That date was a "Spring-ahead" cutover for Daylight Saving Time (DST).
And such a moment is generally best communicated as a value with an offset of zero, if business rules do not demand knowledge of the original time zone. So the startOfDay above should be converted to an Instant, always in UTC, with an offset of zero.
Instant startOfDayUtc = startOfDayAmman.toInstant() ;


startOfDayUtc.toString() = 2021-03-25T22:00:00Z

Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format, with a date, a time-of-day, and an offset of zero abbreviated as Z (pronounced “Zulu time”).
String output = startOfDayUtc.toString() ;

Parsing in the other direction.
Instant instant = Instant.parse( … ) ;

What is an offset and time zone?

An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead or behind the temporal meridian of UTC. Moments in the east are represented some hours ahead, and to the west, behind (in ISO 8601 compatible protocols).  A time zone is much more.
A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region as decided by their politicians.


I can interpret a "date with offset" as "date at midnight with offset"

No, incorrect. You cannot. As I explained above, not all dates in all zones start at 00:00. You cannot assume when a day starts. You need the name of a time zone to look up the rules that dictate when the day starts.
Tip: Stop thinking about "midnight" in your date-time handling. The term is nebulous, and troublesome. Instead, focus on the moment when a new day begins according to the rules of a particular time zone.

Does anybody have an idea how to handle "dates with offset"?

Yes.
My idea is to reject such values as nonsensical. Demand sensible inputs if your stakeholders want you to produce sensible software & data.
If your bosses instruct you to assume a start-of-day at 00:00 with  said offset, then get that instruction in writing. When things go awry, that writing may help you — but probably not, as people still blame the programmer!
// I do *NOT* recommend this code, but if you insist…
String datePortion = input.substring( … ) ;
String offsetPortion = input.substring( … ) ;

LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( datePortion ) ;
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.parse( offsetPortion ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( ld , ZoneOffset.MIN , offset ) ;

